# How to stop upload zero bytes images in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Here I choose multiple images for upload, After choosing images I go in that folder where this choosen images placed and change choosen imagename or delete choosen image so now this choosen image goes 0B(see in below image), so I try to stop upload using if condtion ( if(this.fileList[i].size > 0) ) but it only stop that 0B image to upload but I want to stop upload all images to upload how it is possible ?

[image]

TS

```
uploadFiles(){
  if(this.fileList != null && this.fileList != undefined && this.fileList.length > 0){
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.fileList.length; i++) {
      if(this.fileList[i].size > 0){
        formData.append('uploadFiles',this.fileList[i],this.fileList[i].name);
      }else{
        alert("not allow to upload zero bytes images");
      }
    }
    formData.append('urlOfFolder',this.data.urlOfFolder);
    this.userService.saveUploadFiles(formData).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        if(data != undefined && data.status == 1 && data.payload != undefined){
          console.log(data.payload);
        }
      }           
    )
  }else{
    alert("not allow to upload");
  }     
}
```

Comment: i would say that this needs to be a server-side validation, as you can't trust your frontend, you can use ``this.fileList[i].size`` to get the file size, but you should do the validation in the server as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(this.fileList[i].size > 0){
    formData.append('uploadFiles',this.fileList[i],this.fileList[i].name);
} else {
    alert("not allow to upload zero bytes images");
    return; /* return the function and it won't upload anything */
}
```

If I understood you correctly, if you find a 0B picture, you want to cancel all upload and do nothing? If that is correct, you just need to return the function and do nothing.

Comment: yes u understood me correctly i want to cancel all uploads

Comment: @AmishaRana Then this should be the solution.